# Why is my event listener unbinding from my button after two clicks?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates, django-views

I've got an event listener on a like button that should stay bound to it after any amount of clicks but after the second time clicking, it unbinds its self. There is a script on the main html doc and one on the replacement doc (because the script doesn't see the replacement). I've tried passing the whole script tag to the html through context but that didn't work, tried passing just the path to the script tag but that didn't work, tried adding `addEventListener()` on success in the ajax functions but that didn't work either. Can anyone tell me why it unbinds its self? I'm new to JavaScript/JQuery so all of this is new to me and I don't understand how it unbinds its self.

The code is fairly long so I apologize in advance

handle_likes.js (snippet)

```
$(".like-post-btn").on('click', function(){
    console.log("Thing was clicked!"); // sanity check

    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "not-liked") {
        like_post();
    }
    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "is-liked") {
        unlike_post();
    }
});
function unlike_post(){
    console.log("Unlike post called...") // sanity check
    console.log("Test JQuery unlike post..");
    console.log($("#post_id"));
    console.log($("#post_type"));
    $.ajax({
        url: "posting/unlike_post/",
        data: {
            post_id : $("#post_id").val(),
            post_type : $("#post_type").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.like-stuff').html(data);
            },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! Please contact an admin for we have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

feed.html (main template - snippet)

```
               <!-- If revisiting a liked post -->
                <div class="like-stuff">
                {% if not request.user|user_liked_post:post %}
                <button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Like</button>
                {% else %}
                <button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Unlike</button>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="like-count">{{post.like_count}}<div>

                {% if not request.user|user_disliked_post:post %}
                <button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>Dislike</button>
                {% else %}
                <button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>Undislike</button>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="dislike-count">{{post.dislike_count}}</div>
                </div>
<script src="static/js/handle_likes.js"></script>
```

likes.html (replacement html)

```
<!--The top two buttons are the only way I could pass the id and type after the first click-->
<button id="post_id" value="{{post_id}}" hidden="">id: {{post_id}}</div>
<button id="post_type" value="{{post_type}}" hidden="">type: {{post_type}}</div>
<div class="like-stuff">
<button class='like-post-btn' value="{{like_btn_val}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>{{like_btn}}</button>
<h1>{{like_count}}</h1>

<button class='dislike-post-btn' value="{{dislike_btn_val}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>{{dislike_btn}}</button>
<h1>{{dislike_count}}</h1>
</div>
<script src="static/js/handle_likes.js"></script>
```

views.py (unlike function)

```
@login_required
def unlike_post(request, **kwargs):              
    if request.is_ajax():
        post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
        post_type = request.GET.get('post_type')

        print("Debug in like_post line 493:",post_id, post_type)

        if not post_id or not post_type:
            raise Exception("Post id or Post type not passed to 'unlike post' please fix it")
        post = toolz.get_post(post_id, post_type)

        if user_liked(post, request.user):
            delete_like(post, request.user)
            like_count = post.like_count

            # Start context variables
            dislike_btn = "Dislike"
            dislike_btn_val = "not-disliked"
            dislike_count = post.dislike_count
            data = {
            'post_id': post_id,
            'post_type': post_type,
            'like_count': like_count,
            'like_btn': 'Like',
            'like_btn_val': 'not-liked',
            'dislike_btn': dislike_btn,
            'dislike_btn_val': dislike_btn_val,
            'dislike_count': dislike_count
            }
            return render(None, 'likes.html', data)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("You're trying to unlike the post twice...stop it")
    else:
        raise Exception("Not ajax")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dynamically load content or replacing the html content with AJAX, you need to update your click function syntax to following:

```
$(document).on('click', ".like-post-btn", function(){
    console.log("Thing was clicked!"); // sanity check

    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "not-liked") {
        like_post();
    }
    if ($(".like-post-btn").val() == "is-liked") {
        unlike_post();
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!! I had to delete the script tag on the replacement html because unlike_post() was called twice when I clicked it. I'm going to guess and say that the main doc script wasn't seeing the buttons because I had the script start listening before the document was even ready. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, events assign to elements while renedering, so if we wish to assign events for existing and upcoming elements, we need to follow document syntax

Comment: Thank you again, do you happen to have a link to good docs for ajax/JQuery? Also,do you know if Angular JS is easier to work with than all this? I know it's supposed to be a kind of powerhouse.

Comment: I personally suggest you to have a glance at the [official document](https://api.jquery.com/) first. Try all the examples and events which are available in document. Then, you can try to upgrade yourself with other video tutorials, articles etc.